# python -> password safety program

Tags: python, time, brute-force, combinations

i decided to write a brute force function to show people how vulnerable a password is. right now, i can show them the list it goes through to find the password, but how do i tell them how long it took?
here's the code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import itertools

lower_a = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z']
upper_a = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z']
num = ['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9']

alllet = []
alllet = lower_a + upper_a# + num
pwd = raw_input("What pwd?\t\t")

try:
        for r in range(1, len(pwd)+1):
                for s in itertools.product(alllet, repeat=r):
                        print ''.join(s)
                        if ''.join(s) == pwd:
                                raise NameError()

except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print "Hey! You stopped me!"

except NameError:
        print "DONE! CRACKED!"
        print "\n\nPassword is:\t" + ''.join(s) + "\n\n"
```

Comment: Incidentally, `from string import printable` may be helpful.

Comment: Just a tip for your `lower_a`, `upper_a` and `num` lists: `import string` and use `list(string.lowercase)`, `list(string.uppercase)` and `list(string.digits).`

Comment: string.printable = string.lowercase + string.uppercase + string.digits + string.punctuation + string.whitespace

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all passwords are quite safe and it will take many many days to find one using brute force attack.

But if you'd like you could use following:

```
import time

start_time = time.time()

# Your code here

stop_time = time.time()
print "Running time in sec:", stop_time - start_time
```

Comment: i'll accept if you upvote? or is that just not the kinda thing we do here

Comment: I don't think that's how it's done. Is the answer correct? If so, accept it. If not, don't.

Comment: You can always vote up if you like the question or answer and it is your right to accept any answer which works for you. From FAQ: `Reputation is completely optional. Normal use of Stack Overflow — that is, asking and answering questions — does not require any reputation whatsoever.`

Answer (score 1):

What you need is the `timeit` module. Using `timeit.Timer`, you can measure the speed of your code.

[Here](http://www.pastequestion.com/blog/python/is-your-code-fast-find-out-with-timeit.html) is a good online tutorial.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

How long as in time?

`from time import time` on top, at the start of the program do `start = time()`. at the nameerror part do `print time() - start`

please be a bit more specific